# Show that$\sum_{r\text{ odd}}^n r {n \choose r} = n2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I want to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{r\text{ odd}}^n r {n \choose r} = n2^{n-2}$ while $r$ is odd.

I have been able to show that:
$\sum_{r=0}^n r {n \choose r} = n2^{n-1}$ for all indices.

How can I go from the second expression to the first.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

Expand $(1-x)^n$ and differentiate it to show that
$$\sum_{r\text{ even}}r\binom nr=\sum_{r\text{ odd}}r\binom nr.$$

Comment: How can it be concluded?

Comment: I would call something like this a sketch rather than a hint.

Comment: @GADI:You know the total sum, and each of the sums (for $r$ even and $r$ odd) is equal to the other, hence they're equal to half the total sum.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You're right, but I don't see how to make a real hint and no more for this one.

Comment: I mean how did you show that they are equal by expanding $(1-x)^n$?

Comment: Setting $x=1$, you obtain $0$.

Comment: @GADI : Notice that when $x=1,$ then $(1-x)^n=0.$ Expanding by using the binomial theorem, you get $$ (1-x)^n = 
\sum_{r=0}^n \binom n r (-x)^r. $$ Differentiating, you get $$ n(1-x)^{n-1}(-1) = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom n r r(-x)^{r-1}(-1). $$ Plug $x=1$ into the left side and you get $0$ (provided $n\ge 2$). And on the right side you get negative terms and positive terms, corresponding to whether $r$ is even or odd. $\qquad$

Comment: That's ingenious. Absolutely loved it!

Answer (score 3):

The combinatorial interpretation is straightforward:
$$ \sum_{\substack{0\leq r \leq n\\ r\text{ odd}}}r\binom{n}{r} $$
is the number of ways for picking, among $n$ people, a committee with an odd number of members and elect a chief of such committee. In a equivalent way, we may pick the chief first ($n$ ways), then an even number of people from the remaining $n-1$. It follows that
$$ \sum_{\substack{0\leq r \leq n\\ r\text{ odd}}}r\binom{n}{r} = n 2^{n-2} $$
since $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ has the same number of subsets with even/odd cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look at $((1+x)^n-(1-x)^n)/2$.